# Som maquina de escrever!

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou aqui para iniciar um projeto mas estou com alguma duvida?, eu necessito de som de maquina de escrever ao escrever em um formulário, por exemplo ao clicar em uma tecla reproduz o som dando um efeito de som de maquina de escrever. Alguem sabe se e possível e que me possa facultar alguma documentação?

Comment: Não entendi o que você está querendo... o som de máquina de escrever ou não sabe como reproduzir um audio no key up?

Comment: sim e mesmo isso nao sei como reproduzir um som com o keyup

Comment: então veja a pergunta indicada lá em e edite a sua caso não consiga, apresentando exatamente onde encontrou dificuldade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo que pode te ajudar:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Maquina de Escrever</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var clack = new Audio('http://www.sounddogs.com/previews/104/mp3/561076_SOUNDDOGS__co.mp3');
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#campo").keyup(function() {
    clack.play();
   });
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="campo">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: O jQuery aí seria apenas para fazer o `keyup`?

Comment: e mesmo isso muito obrigado!!

Comment: Seria melhor com o keydown em vez do keyup!

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, como você faz para as palavras nos comentários ficarem marcadas?

Comment: @Le248dev Acento grave, tal como é nas perguntas/respostas.

Comment: Valeu amigo, é que começei no stack esses dias e não sabia.